# Using light color in Lazarus (Pascal, crt)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Does anyone know a way to use light colors in Lazarus?
I'm using the crt library, which says that, for example, 2=Green and 10=LightGreen.

```
TextBackground(2);
clrscr;
readln;
TextBackground(10);
clrscr;
readln;
```

However, for some reason, in Lazarus they both output the same color (I'm using the above example in a Lazarus simple program with the crt library. Using the identifiers "Green" and "LightGreen" gives the same result).

Does anyone know a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: As I remember there is no `Light` modifier for the background colors in the terminal, only for foreground. Also it could to depend on terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "terminal emulator"? I'm not an expert at this.   The crt library states the colors exist, but they don't specify foreground/background.   Do you know of any way to get lighter colors, for example a pure white background or two different green colors?

Comment: "_Could you explain what you mean by "terminal emulator"?_" - [Terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). In few words: "Terminal emulator " is the program that emulates the behavior of the [hardware terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal). "_Do you know of any way to get lighter colors_" - no, and I am not sure that it is possible at all for background colors for every terminal emulator that exists.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I had looked up the definition but I still don't understand. I'm running a simple program in the console, with Lazarus. I am not sure if this is useful

Comment: @Mihaila: On some OSes and some terminal emulators, it is possible, on some others it isn't possible to set the background to a light colour. Which OS are you using? Note that the Crt unit comes from Turbo Pascal and was originally for DOS only. It has been changed to work on other terminal emulators, but not all of it will work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, because I had solved this sometime after posting, but had forgotten about the question.

I'll start by saying I have NO IDEA why this works, and that I found out about it by accident.

Running this code has given me a white background, and it has worked for any other light colour.

```
  TextBackground(15);
  TextColor(Black+ Blink);
  ClrScr;
  readln;
```

If anyone could post any explanation as to why this works, I'll be happy to set it as best answer.